# FAB button animation not working properly

Tags: css, button, css-animations, floating-action-button

I'm trying to animate a FAB button when it's clicked. I want it to open and fills up the screen - It's for a responsive webApp running in mobile devices.

The problem is: When I click to open the button, it gets the full width instantly and then animate up. And to close the button, it shorten instantly and then animate down.

The problem is I'm using a fixed position, so I don't know how to deal with it.

This is an code example:

html:

```
<div class="fab" ng-class="{'open': fabOpen}" ng-click="toggleFab()">
    <span ng-show="!fabOpen">FAB</span>
    <h4 ng-show="fabOpen">Just a test</h4>
</div>
```

scss:

```
$time: 400ms;
.fab {
    -webkit-transition-duration:    $time;
    -moz-transition-duration:       $time;
    -o-transition-duration:         $time;
    transition-duration:            $time;

    border-radius:50%;
    background:#358FE8;
    display:inline-block;
    height:80px;
    line-height:80px;
    width:80px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:16px;
    right:16px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    &.open {
        background:#fff;
        color:black;
        border:1px solid #eee;
        border-radius:2px;
        left: 16px;
        width:auto;
        height:90%;
    }
}
```

And this is an live demo of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/tfrxf0p5/

Comment: What is the desire? To expand height and width at equal intervals?

Comment: @leigero doesn't need to be completely perfect. But as you can see in the demo, when openning, the width takes full-width without animation, samething when closing. I'd like it to be smooth, and no abrupt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to fix the issue I had was to use a `width:calc;` and doesn't use the `left` property.

This way I can calculate the maximum width of the element based on the distance of the border. So, since I already have a position right of `16px` I need to have a width of 100% minus 16px for each side.

Final code would be something like this:

```
&.open {
    width:calc(100% - 32px);
    /*left:16px;*/ //Doesn't need it
}
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle.

Comment: Although it doesn't work on all browsers I'm still gonna give you an upvote as this code is simple yet effective. Might not want to forget about the vendor prefixes though.

Comment: Oh, sure.. This is for example only. Thanks =D

Answer (score 0):

I can't fix the fiddle on my phone for some reason. you have `transition-duration` but you never set what to `transition`.

Comment: Didn't understood what you said. You mean to define the `transition-property`? Because there is some properties changing, like width, height, color, background, etc..

Comment: You never set the `transition property` not to mention that `auto` is not animatable

Comment: How should I fix it then?

Comment: Set `transition: (what) (how long) ` and set the 'width' to something other than auto

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not setting it based on the width, I'm setting it based on left  and right position, because it's a fixed element. If I use a value for the width, such as 100%, or other, it will not have the proper visual effect, the element will go over the side border.

Comment: Then give it a parent div with width auto and set a width in the fab, there is no way of animating auto

Comment: Can you show an example? Because there is no way I can make it work. Even when using a parent div, the animation is still weird.

Comment: If you really can't set the `width` you'll have to do it in javascript.

Comment: I did it using `calc()` =D